# Best practice to solve Livewire UI Not updating until after API call

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel Livewire, I currently have a form that captures a user's address information, then it needs to submit that to a 3rd party API (it's for billing information).

The issue that I am facing is that the UI doesnt update / livewire doesnt call `render` until after the entire method has run - which looks on the frontend like the UI is frozen / system isnt doing anything as the API is slow and takes a few seconds (15 - 20) to give a response.

I want to be able to trigger a browser event to display an alert saying the request is processing / show an alert banner on the page that it is processing before making the API request, process the API request, then display the results.

Currently I have identified the following ways to make this happen:

1. make the updates on the frontend, fire off an event with the data needed. Laravel event listener handles the API call, and emits a result event that the livewire component listens for, then the livewire component updates the page with the results.
2. make the updates on the frontend, dispatch a job to run in a queue worker, emit an event that the livewire component listens for, update the page with the results.
3. emit an event from the livewire component to itself, the livewire component then listens for that event and processes the API request, then updates the frontend with the results.
4. emit an event from the livewire component to itself to update the UI with processing info, while it still runs the API process in the original method call, and then updates the UI once the API gets a response

My thoughts are, what would be best practice here? All the above solutions require a different amount of work to get running, and solution 1  and 2 looks like complete overkill for such a simple process.

Does this come down to preference? Or is there actually a best practice way to do this in livewire?

And additionally, is there another way / simpler way to do this that I havnt mentioned above?

Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/loading-states#toggling-elements "Elements with the wire:loading directive are only visible while waiting for actions to complete (network requests)."

Comment: @ceejayoz I did try that, it is a generic thing, so I cant specifically target a specific message or action using just `wire:loading` as the state hasnt updated by then

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem. Did you ever find a solution @Haring10?

Comment: @Drowsy yes I did find a solution. I used events and emitted an event to itself (same component) to then run the function to redirect. So notify the user with a toast message / update the UI -> emit event -> receive emitted event -> handle redirect

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a job and then return a response to the user. Then instigate Livewire polling that can check for the job being complete. If the API takes 15-20 seconds then polling once per second should be fine.
You might want to store the state in the database so that the job and the livewire component can communicate with each other.  If you don't need to keep the data, using the cache to communicate between job and component would be a good alternative.